# After adding google_mobile_ads: ^0.13.1 dependency my application doesn`t build(run)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-mobile-ads

**The error!**

Launching lib\main.dart on SM J530F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\Hemmat.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\7ba8a5d002061257f3e1886457266628\play-services-ads-lite-20.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml:27:5-43:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element  found in .

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 14s
The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin connectivity...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'connectivity'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s

Exception: The plugin connectivity could not be built due to the issue above.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved this error this way,
Change this things in your project,

1. In build.gradle change to classpath
   'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
2. In gradle-wrapper.properties change to
   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip